# How to output text node value line by line using xslt 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have a xml file which is like:

```
<Messages>
   error message 1

   error message 2 
</Messages>
```

I would like to have the output as:

```
Error 1: 
error message 1

Error 2:
error message 2
```

I'm using xslt 1.0, and I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Messages">
    <h3>Error 1:</h3>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(./text(), '&#10;')"/>
    <h3>Error 2:</h3>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(./text(), '&#10;')"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it returned me nothing...Could anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this recursive template to achieve this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="Messages" name="outputError">
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="source" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisLine" select="normalize-space(substring-before($source, '&#10;'))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="theRest" select="substring-after($source, '&#10;')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$thisLine">
        <h3>Error <xsl:value-of select="$index"/>:</h3>
        <span><xsl:value-of select="$thisLine"/></span>
        <xsl:call-template name="outputError">
          <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index + 1"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="source" select="$theRest"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$theRest">
        <xsl:call-template name="outputError">
          <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="source" select="$theRest"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wrapped the actual errors in a `<span>` element just to clearly separate them from whitespace, you can of course your a `<p>`, `<div>` or no element at all if you prefer.

Comment: +1 for the $index parameter which makes the whole transformation more extensible~BTW, do you have any idea about why didn't my transformation work?

Comment: I suspect it's because your text actually contains a `&#10;` BEFORE the first error- the `<Messages>` open tag and the first error are on separate lines. My template will actually skip any empty lines, including the first one.

Answer (score 1):

**If I must use XSLT 1.0, I would write a two-pass transformation like this:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
      <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*/line
       [preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text() and normalize-space()]]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*/text()" name="markUp">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="normalize-space($pText)">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText,'&#xA;'), '&#xA;')"/>
      <line/>
      <xsl:call-template name="markUp">
        <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText,'&#xA;')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
Error: <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), '&#xA;')"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(preceding-sibling::node()[1])"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Messages>
   error message 1

   error message 2
</Messages>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
Error: 1
error message 1

Error: 2
error message 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not getting it...For this "ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)/*/line
       [preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text() and normalize-space()]]" expression, where does the 'line' come from? And what nodesets does variable $vrtfPass1 copy from?

Comment: @D.Q., `line` is an element name. `line` elements are generated in the first pass of the transformation. In XSLT 1.0 one generally needs to convert the captured result (of a pass of a transformation) from the infamous RTF (Result Tree Fragment) type, to a regular tree. This conversion is performed using a vendor-specific extension function (named usually `node-set()`) that resides in a vendor-defined namespace. This solution uses the EXSLT `node-set()` extension, because EXSLT is implemented by the majority of XSLT 1.0 processors and thus provides some degree of portability.